# Parsing text to find geographic names

Tags: java, parsing, gis

i want to write a parser which search some city names or other geographic topics in a large count of textes. For example `Sydney`,`Tower Bridge`,`Munich`...

My idea is to request some words to a local database with informations about geography(such http://www.geonames.org/, there i can download some cityinformations) if there is a hit, the database response some lan and lon coordinats. The words must start with upper case letter and must be a length>2

But i think that the performance is very worse. One text contains 10 to 100 words.
Is there a better method to find geoinformations about a text?

And maybe there is a better database with more geoinformations?

Greetings,
destiny

Comment: Try it. Parsing in Java is quite fast. You might not run into issues

Comment: The hard part is to find the words you need to look for as a list.  Then you can split in words, and find any words that qualify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to index the text files using a library such as [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) and then search for each of Cities in the list. The results would give you the file name and the location of the term (with surrounding text snippet)

Comment: jeah! it looks very simple and great :) Found some tutorials at http://www.lucenetutorial.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the google JSON API: [Search for Baltimore MD](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Baltimore%20MD&sensor=true)

Comment: jeah of course, but than i need for every word a own request. That's very worse for the performance. And i think the reuqats to the google api are limited for each API_KEY/User